# digital envelope routines: bad decrypt on big file | C programming

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

so school gave us a project (encrypt files of a dir, then decrypt it)
the teacher gave us a part of the code. Here it is https://pastebin.com/g4BfVA8a

So my script works fine with a tiny size, i can encrypt and decrypt it like a charm.
But when i try why the /home, when i decrypt it i get this error:

```
rm: cannot remove '/home/kali/.mozilla/firefox/Crash': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'Reports/InstallTime20200914174320.Pwnd': No such file or directory
140470750399488:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:../crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:610:
zsh: abort      sudo ./main -p /home/kali -d  28924fd9021642cee4002de561b52640
```

My key/iv cant be wrong cuz i copy pasted from the server i writed.
Any idea?
little part of my script:

```
if(is_encrypted(abs_path))
                    {
                        if(decrypt(key, iv, abs_path))
                        {
                            char str[4099];
                            sprintf(str, "rm %s", abs_path);
                            system(str);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            handleErrors();
                            printf("%s caused the error", abs_path);
                        }
```

refer to comments, here is more code. It's how i declare my key/iv size.

```
int sizeKey = AES_256_KEY_SIZE;
int sizeIv = AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
unsigned char key[AES_256_KEY_SIZE];
unsigned char iv[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
char *pKey = (char*)malloc(sizeof(key)*2+1);
char *pIv = (char*)malloc(sizeof(iv)*2+1);
```

into

```
generate_key(key, sizeKey, iv, sizeIv, pKey, pIv);
int generate_key(unsigned char *key, int sizeKey, unsigned char *iv, 
int sizeIv,char *pKey, char *pIv)
{
    RAND_bytes(key, sizeKey);
    RAND_bytes(iv, sizeKey);
    bytes_to_hexa(key, pKey, sizeKey);
    bytes_to_hexa(iv, pIv, sizeIv);
    return 1;
}
```

then sending to my server.

when i decrypt i do:
./main -p PATH -d KEY IV
while key iv are retransformed into bytes key/iv.

Comment: *My key/iv cant be wrong ... Any idea?* You're not going to want to hear it but my idea is that your key/iv is wrong. We can't see how you're processing command-line parameters and/or generating the key/iv, but the only argument to your script is something that looks like 32 hex characters -- or 128 bits, and you're using AES with keysize of 256 bits. That's at least a mismatch, so I'd start looking there.

Comment: SO is not a website to do your homework. What did you try to fix your mistake ? Did you try to debug step by step ? Furthermore, how are we supposed to help with so little details ?

Comment: Please refer to the edit.

Comment: That code from the edits looks wrong. `AES_256_KEY_SIZE` should be 32 and `AES_BLOCK_SIZE` should be 16, therefore you cannot use a single length variable `sizeKey` in `generate_key` to contain the length of both because those lengths are different. If the code really is accurate then you have a heap or buffer overflow at `RAND_bytes(iv, sizeKey);`

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, oh well haven't seen this mistake on rand_bytes()... fixed it. but same error

Comment: Even if you fixed it the code is still incomplete and my original comment is still true -- why do you have a 16 byte key on the command-line when it should be 32 bytes?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, the error code is a bit weird because my command line is:
sudo ./main -p /home/kali -d 177e3937ce4a68aeac35eef1e3da5aa82979fad9fd016c273265b0208af97a8f e8cff569bc6f31625ff7b965100e04a9
so error code refer to IV

And this works for tiny file like home/kali/test_dir. Here it bugs w /home/kali. Sudo issue? config openssl file in /home?